# How to pass special character from C# to JavaScript via ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: javascript, c#, special-characters, scriptmanager

I want to pass a string that contain a special character as a paramaert of JS function from C# like the following:

```
string param = "sm~aEkv{yEb@~IX`GVhG@\\BZ@bA?L";
string jsFunction = "viewPathOnMap(\"" + param+ "\");";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", jsFunction, true);
```

When I am debugging in the JavaScript side, I find the value is received as:

```
sm~aEkv{yEb@~IX`GVhG@BZ@bA?L
```

not like:

```
sm~aEkv{yEb@~IX`GVhG@\BZ@bA?L
```

What I can do in this case?

Comment: You declare the string as `string param = "sm~aEkv{yEb@~IX`GVhG@\\BZ@bA?L"`, so why would you want to backslash to completely disappear?

Comment: @Samathingamajig I am sorry, my mistake. I meant the opposite. Pls, check my edit.

Comment: Try double escaping it ( \\\\ )

Comment: try ```@``` before string.. ```string param = @"sm~aEkv{yEb@~IX`GVhG@\\BZ@bA?L"; ```